# Alert is not Showing when i tried to call it in listview with condition

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone am trying to show an alert popup in the listview in the flutter app with condition check but my pop is not showing below is my code please help

```
ListView _buildListViewOfDevices() {
    List<Container> containers = <Container>[];
    for (BluetoothDevice device in widget.devicesList) {
      if (device.name == 'Airbud Pro Plus') {
        Alert(
          context: context,
          title: 'Greetings',
          desc: 'you are using Apple Airbud Pro Plus',
        ).show();
      }
```

Comment: Where is `Alert` coming from? Is it a custom widget or an external package?

Comment: if my answer solved your issue mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Are you using this package? https://pub.dev/packages/alert Please add that to your question if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

below is how you show an alert dialog:

```
ListView _buildListViewOfDevices(context) { //pass context as parameter
      List<Container> containers = <Container>[];
      for (BluetoothDevice device in widget.devicesList) {
        if (device.name == 'Airbud Pro Plus') {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('greetings!!'),
                    content: Text("you are using Apple Airbud Pro Plus"),
                  ));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this but it gives me error

Comment: i think we cant use showDialog in listview and gridview

Comment: what error did you get

Comment: App crash overlay error

Comment: alert dialog have nothing to do with listview. how many "Airbud Pro Plus" you have in list, if there is more than one, so the error might be alert dialog trying to be shown more than once causing overlay error. in that case you need to declare a bool variable to check if the alert dialog was shown already and prevent it from showing again however this is just a guess..

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using rflutter_alert package:

function call example:

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Basic Alert'),
              onPressed: () => _onBasicAlertPressed(context),
            ),
```

function body example:

```
_onBasicAlertPressed(context) {
    Alert(
            context: context,
            title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
            desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.")
        .show();
  }
```

Reference link: https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert/tree/master/example

Comment: thanks for your logic thats totally fine but i want to show popup in listview with out pressing button popup will show when a bluetooth device of name Airbud scanned and show in listview